# Spark -- Loading log4j from JAR running spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, spark-submit

I have developed a custom log4j to my spark application:

```
#######################
#    Roll by time     #
#######################
log4j.logger.myLogger=DEBUG, file 
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern = contactabilidad_%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
```

I packged my project into a JAR, and I run it in spark-submit.

I just want write the logs into a file, as I do it, when the file **log4j.properties** is into the file system from where I run the spark-submit and I define this path in the command java-options.

```
spark-submit --class com.path.to.class.InitialContactDriver 
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" 
--master yarn    /home/cloudera/SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**My point is:** *Can't I reference the log file which is inside of the JAR?*

[image: content inside of the JAR]

As I do it with the class: *--class com.path.to.class.InitialContactDriver*

I am going to run the app into limited environment and I would like not upload files into the FS, just use it what I have in the JAR.
Is that possible? And if it not, why not?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide the `--driver-class-path` option in your command. Try with:

```
spark-submit --class com.path.to.class.InitialContactDriver \
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" \
--driver-class-path /home/cloudera/SNAPSHOT.jar \
--master yarn    /home/cloudera/SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I haven't tried with YARN, but in local mode and cluster mode worked fine.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer :) I've tried and I got this **error** "log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)".

Comment: Yeah, sorry, try without `file:` both in --driver-java-options and --conf. So:
spark-submit --class com.path.to.class.InitialContactDriver \
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" \
--driver-class-path /home/cloudera/SNAPSHOT.jar \
--master yarn    /home/cloudera/SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: That resolved completly my problem. Thank so much! :)

Comment: Does it work for YARN... As i have tried all these options in YARN CLuster mode but no Success